# move xml file from folder to another folder depend on condition in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I just have to move xml file from folder to another folder based on xml tag comment , for example :

```
If :
1- comment tag is  Student1 will be move to folder Student_1
2- comment tag is Student2 will be move to folder Student_2
```

xml :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<!--Student1 grades are uploaded by months-->
<class_list>
   <student>
      <name>Tanmay</name>
      <grade>A</grade>
   </student>
</class_list>
```

any advise ,

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Grep` has a useful exit status so something like this should do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if grep -q '^<!--Student1.*-->$' file.xml; then
  echo cp file.xml Student_1
elif grep -q '^<!--Student2.*-->$' file.xml; then
  echo cp file.xml Student_2
fi
```

Remove the `echo`'s if you're satisfied with the output so cp can actually copy files.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
if [ ! -z "$(grep "Student1" file.xml)" ]
then
  cp file.xml Student_1
elif [ ! -z "$(grep "Student2" file.xml)"]
then
  cp file.xml Student_2
fi`
```

If you need something more for multiple students you could try this:

```
studentline="$(grep "Student" file.xml)"
student=$(echo $studentline| cut -d'-' -f 3)
student=${student%% *}
echo $student
```

This extracts the student for you and with this you would get the number:

```
student=${student##*t}
```

With that you can make a pretty easy function to move it in the right folder